# iOS - Fixed bootstrap navbar content is completely transparent

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am currently working on a project made by someone else and I discovered a bug that is happening only on iOS devices. The webpage is using bootstrap navbar for the menu. There are 2 menu buttons on the page in the navbar - the left one is working correctly but the right one has a strange bug. You can see it live here https://www.sanatoriums.com/en/our-team. Initially the navbar is hidden behind the contact box so you have to scroll down a little. http://prntscr.com/paurza

The menu content slides from the side after clicking on the button. In every other mobile browser this works as it should, but on iOS the menu actually slides out but it is completely TRANSPARENT (background, text, everything). You can click the items in the menu, you just can't see them. It seems like I'm missing some property and with out it Safari is going crazy.

I searched and tried bunch of fixes recommended for iOS hoping it could be it but wasn't succesful. Would be very thankful for help in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what was causing the bug. It was solved by adding `overflow: visible` to the .navbar class